# Adding WMS Service for Silverlight Viewer

Tags: wms, arcgis-silverlight-api

Is there a way to add a WMS image service in basemap gallery?

Answer (score 2):

Do You mean ArcGIS Viewer for Silverlight?
You can edit .\Config\Map.xml file and add some lines of code after esri:Map.Extent  tag

```
<!--WMS Service Definition-->
<esri:WmsLayer ID="OtherWMSLayer"
             Url="http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi"
             ProxyUrl="http://serverapps.esri.com/SilverlightDemos/ProxyPage/proxy.ashx"
             SkipGetCapabilities="False"
             Layers="nexrad-n0r"
             Version="1.1.1"
             Opacity="0.7"
             esriExtensibility:MapApplication.LayerName="Weather Radar"/>
```

Regards,
Kuba

Comment: Will this layer be animating to show the weather radar moving?  If not, what's the trick to adding animated weather radar to a silverlight map?